# How to return List of String as Error message in response while throwing an error?

Tags: java, exception

I have created a custom exception and I want to throw an Exception which throws the exception with the list of integer. How do I do that? I know I can simple pass a message in Exception. But I want to pass a List as a Message in exception.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<Integer> invalidAges = new ArrayList<>();
         for(int i = 0 ; i <10;i++) invalidAges.add(i);

    throw new InvalidAgesException(invalidAges); 
    }
}

class InvalidAgesException extends RuntimeException {
    private final List<Integer> invalidAges;

    public InvalidAgesException(List<Integer> invalidAges) {
        this.invalidAges = invalidAges;
    }

    public List<Integer> getInvalidAges() {
        return invalidAges;
    }
}
```

Output should be :
Exception: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: You are already passing List of Integers to the custom exception class.

Comment: If the purpose of the exception is only to print the list you can pass invalidAges.toString() to it. If not can you explain better what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your code here is fine, but I presume you're looking for the exception to actually print your list to the stack trace.

In this case you can just pass it to the constructor of `RuntimeException` which accepts a `String` as a message:

```
public InvalidAgesException(List<Integer> invalidAges) {

    super(invalidAges.toString());
    this.invalidAges = invalidAges;
}
```

Alternatively you can override the `getMessage` method of the exception:

```
public String getMessage() {

    return invalidAges.toString();
}
```

Comment: See that's the thing. I want to pass a display a list rather than a string.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. This does pass a list - `invalidAges`?

Comment: How would you display a list of strings? Let's say the list was `{"String1", "String2", "String3"}`, then what would you "display"?

Comment: Rather than displaying ```"[String1,String2,String3]"``` , I want to display ```[String1,String2,String3]```.
The sole reason behind passing a list is that I am actually passing List of objects in exception and I want to use those objects in frontend.

Comment: If you want to display them as `[String1,String2,String3]`, then that's a string??

Comment: Let me try to explain in better way. When we use CustomException, we can pass a custom message to Exception while throwing an exception. In that message I want to pass a ArrayList and Not String. Can we do that? Rather than doing ```throw new exception(list.toString())``` I want to do like ```throw new Exception(new ArrayList<>())```

Comment: Absolutely you can, that's what my answer gives you. So you can call `throw new InvalidAgesException(new ArrayList<>())`.

Comment: Yes I know I am that will pass a list to my exception. But I need to return this list from getMessage() and without converting it to string.

Comment: You can't change Java's native behaviour. They use the `getMessage` method for printing the exception to the console so it returns a string. I'm not sure why you would want anything different?